# Aasy flip a column code

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please explain me the VBA code below?

I am fairly new to VBA coding, so whenever I encounter something in my work routine that I feel can be done more efficiently or faster I search for VBA codes on the internet and adjust these to my need. This works fairly well most of the time. However in time I also want to be able to write them myself from scratch.

EDIT:

*So this time I have a hard time understanding the following simple piece of coding. I tried to gain insight by changing the code to only work for ranges existing out of 1 column, which means changing the for statement and removing the `Ubound(arr,2)` But I got stuck. Can someone explain me how the code (formula) should look like if I only works on single column ranges?*

```
Sub FlipColumns()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
On Error Resume Next

xTitleId = "ExcelTool"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address,Type:=8)
Arr = WorkRng.Formula
For j = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
    k = UBound(Arr, 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1) / 2
        xTemp = Arr(i, j)
        Arr(i, j) = Arr(k, j)
        Arr(k, j) = xTemp
        k = k - 1
      Next
Next
WorkRng.Formula = Arr
End Sub
```

Comment: It's flipping a column (or columns) of formulas, so if the selected range was A2:A20 then A2 would end up with the formula originally in A20, A3 would end up with the formula originally in A19, ... A20 would end up with the formula originally in A2.  (But you will continue to have a hard time understanding code if you have to ask for someone to explain it to you each time you see something new - you need to learn to look at the code and research any bits you don't understand.)

Comment: Note:  There is also an explanation of what the code does on [the webpage that the code probably comes from](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/712-excel-flip-column.html).

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I know this isn't the best way and I also know what it does, but I was hoping I could find an easier way to gain insight in the actual formula, starting with "for J = 1 to Ubound()  ending with next." Because This formula does the trick for multiple selected colums as well (Ubound(arr,2)) so I thought I'll change the code so it only works when selecting a single column range. But got stuck there ;)

Comment: Providing a tutorial on each of the functions used in each of the statements in the code is too broad for Stack Overflow.  That's what [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/office-vba-reference) is for.  (E.g. look at [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ubound-function) for info on what `UBound` does.)

Comment: ok I think we are mis interpreting eachother haha. I know this is no place to explain Ubound (which I already know btw). I'll rephrase the question ;)

Comment: What do you want to happen if they select multiple columns?  Just process the first one?  Or give an error message and exit the procedure?

Comment: Your edit makes the mistake of assuming that an array of a single column is one dimensioned. In fact, it is a two dimensioned array where the ubound of the second rank is 1.

Comment: doesn't matter. Error or exit ( which is just a line of code like on error exit sub or something no? ) Just want a look at the simpler version of the code,  to understand what it actually does. ;)

Comment: To make this for a single column only, simply redimension WorkRng to a single column (probably the first column) before entering the lop(s). e.g.`Set WorkRng = WorkRng.columns(1)`

Comment: Ok - minimalist change - to process just the first column change `UBound(Arr, 2)` to `1` - i.e. `For j = 1 To 1`.  (Untidy, inefficient, but a simple change.)  An even more minimalist change would be change nothing, but instruct user (yourself?) to select just one column.

Comment: Sorry If these questions are stupid guys, And I know this is not the most efficient post or question, but I really made it a point of understanding this simple code: But thanks anyway! I think I got there a bit more now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to ensure that the users only process a single column, you could just add an `Exit Sub` if they select a multi-column range, e.g.:

```
'...
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address,Type:=8)
If WorkRng.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, only a single column should be selected"
    Exit Sub
End If
'...
```